# Type.GetTypeFromProgID() ID for Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge

I am updating some old code that uses Type.GetTypeFromProgID() and Activator.CreateInstance() to open InternetExplorer. Since IE is out of service, this needs to be updated to use Microsoft Edge.

The ID used for Internet Explorer here was "InternetExplorer.Application", and GetTypeFromProgID() says it checks a registry, but I don't know what registry or what the ID is for Microsoft Edge.

What is the ID for Microsoft Edge and furthermore, where can I find the ID for any application?

I tried Microsoft.Edge.Application and microsoft-edge: based on suggestions from ChatGPT from stackoverflow. Both fail at this line.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), [CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addhostobjecttoscript?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1823.32), and [Call native-side code from web-side code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/hostobject?tabs=win32)

Comment: What is your final purpose? Automatically control Edge through COM interface like IE? If this is the case, then this requirement cannot be met and you need the corresponding WebDriver.